# Set a query on a variable for dbeaver SQL / Multiple line assign variable

Tags: sql, variables, variable-assignment, dbeaver

I was trying to save a query on a variable like:

```
WITH auxiliar AS (
SELECT var1
FROM table
)
SELECT *
FROM aux
```

but instead save the first part on a variable:

```
@set auxiliar = 
SELECT var1
FROM table

SELECT *
FROM (${auxiliar}) AS aux
```

but the second option **does not work on several lines**

The only way for it to work is with:

```
@set auxiliar = SELECT var1 FROM table

SELECT *
FROM (${auxiliar}) AS aux
```

But I'd like to know if it is possible to use some kind of brackets so I can write it on several lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a parameter

```
select * from :auxiliar
```

and then you just have to right your query in the pop up window.

Comment: It is really usefull but still not the thing I require. Thank you!

Comment: I agree that, while nice, this does not solve the problem of assigning a multiple row query or literal value to a variable.